# How to write custom emitEvent for proessing in socket.io?

Tags: node.js, websocket, socket.io, processing, processing.js

I am writing a multi-player game using processing.js, node.js and socket.io.

Question #1:

In the client, I use p5.js to create a class Ball.
I want the server to send parameter to create an array using that class (balls.push(new Ball(x, y));), so every client can have a bunch of balls moving on the canvas.

I know I should use socket.io to emit the parameter to the client but i have no clue.
Normally the array is created inside the setup function inside p5...so how could socket do that?

Question #2:

How could the client send the mouseX and mouseY to the server? And then how could the server send back others' mouseX and mouseY to every client?

I try to make p5.js into normal js like this:

```
         (function () {
            "use strict"; 
                function sketchProc(processing) {
                   var p=processing,
                   var ...,
                   var ...;

                   function ball(){...}

                   p.setup=function(){}
                   p.draw=function(){}
                    }

             var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas1"),
                p = new Processing(canvas, sketchProc);

               }());
```

But i don't know if this helps...

Comment: You probably want to read http://processingjs.org/articles/PomaxGuide.html#interface so that you get an idea of how to make node talk to your JS environment, rather than directly to your sketch. Let the JS talk to your sketch for you after it gets the data from node.

Answer (score 0):

The balls should be passed to the client only in the connection event. That's where node's beauty lies, code sharing.

To create a socket server, you can use either node's native [Net](http://nodejs.org/api/net.html) module or [Socket.io](https://github.com/learnboost/socket.io/)

**On the server:**

```
var server = net.createServer();
server.listen(PORT, HOST);
server.on('connection', function(socket) {    
    socket.write({ type: "BallsArray", data: BallsArray });
});
```

**On the client, you use WebSockets with Socket.io:**

```
var client = io.connect('http://localhost:3000');
var BallsArray = null;
client.on('message', function(msg) {
    if(msg.type == "BallsArray")
        BallsArray = msg.data; 
});
```

Comment: thx, but i still don't know how the server could generate the parameter    balls.push(new Ball(x, y));